# Bootstrap Modal Submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching all over and trying different combinations. I will try to explain exactly what I need. I have a table populated with SQL data, last column is an Edit button to open a bootstrap modal. I've been able to populate the table and create the edit button to pass the row id into the modal for the query on the modal populate all inputs with actual data on DB. Everything is working. But now I can't even make a POST on the form, I hit the button and nothing happens.

```
<?php 
require 'style/header.php';
require 'core/db_connect.php';
?><div class="main">
            <div class="row">
                <table class= "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 180px;" tabindex="0">BI/CC</th>
                            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="0">Name</th>
                            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 288px;" tabindex="0">Supplier Number</th>
                            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 40px;" tabindex="0">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $query = "SELECT bicc, name, supplier_number ";
                    $query .= "FROM ext_work_risk ";
                    $result = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, $query);
                    $i=0;
                    while($fetch = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        if($i%2==0) $class = 'even'; else $class = 'odd';                           
                        echo'<tr class="'.$class.'">
                            <td>'.$fetch['bicc'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$fetch['name'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$fetch['supplier_number'].'</td>                                <td><a class="modalButton" data-bicc="'.$fetch['bicc'].'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_edit" data-container="body">Edit</button></a></td>
                            </tr>';                         
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="modal_edit" class="modal fade" style="font-weight: normal;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">

          </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php require 'style/footer.php' ?>

<!-- Script Part -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.modalButton').click(function(){
        var bicc = $(this).attr('data-bicc');
        $.ajax({url:"modal/ajax_ext_risk_modal_edit.php?bicc="+bicc,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".modal-content").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

Now the **"modal/ajax_ext_risk_modal_edit.php"** file:

```
<?php
$bicc = $_GET['bicc'];
//DB connect settins
require '../core/db_connect.php';
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM ext_work_risk WHERE bicc='$bicc'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, $query);
$fetch = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
?>
  <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Co-Worker</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>To edit just type the new date in the format <b>YYYY/MM/DD</b> and click save.
          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="../core/process_ext_risk_modal.php">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">BI/CC:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input class="form-control" id="bicc" name="bicc" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fetch['bicc']; ?>">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input class="form-control" id="name" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fetch['name']; ?>">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Sup. Number:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input class="form-control" id="supplier_number" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fetch['supplier_number']; ?>">
                </div>
              </div> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4">LOTO:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input class="form-control" id="loto" name="loto" <?php $loto = $fetch['loto']->format('Y/m/d'); if ($loto == "2000/01/01") {echo "placeholder='Please insert date'";} else {echo "value='$loto'";} ?>>
            </div>
          </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Lift Platform:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input class="form-control" id="lift_platform" <?php $lift_platform = $fetch['lift_platform']->format('Y/m/d'); if ($lift_platform == "2000/01/01") {echo "placeholder='Please insert date'";} else {echo "value='$lift_platform'";} ?>>
                </div>
              </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Save</button>
        </div>
```

When I hit Save button nothing happens. Here is the **../core/process_ext_risk_modal.php** file:

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");
if(isset($_POST["save"])) {
  $id = $_POST['bicc'];
  $data = $_POST['loto'];
  if(sqlsrv_query($dbhandle, "update ext_work_risk set loto='$data' where bicc='$id'"))
  echo 'success';
}
?>
```

This last file is just for testing of course I will be Updating much more data on the form submit.

Thank you

Comment: Submit input is outside of form and using the wrong name attribute

Comment: Yes thanks I couldn't get to submit being outside the form. Just fixed that. But can't understand what you mean with wrong name attribute.

Comment: Think I got it, you mean the `if(isset($_POST["save"]))`, it needs to be `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`. I've just changed that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check for errors via php and in your queries. Also look at the console and the html source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the problem thanks to **Fred -ii** tips:

So here is the previous code block:

```
  </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

And now the corrected one:

```
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Save</button>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Also changing `if(isset($_POST["save"]))` to `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`. Main problem being having submit outside form and two types defined on the same button.